# how to add a character string in a row in r

Tags: r

I have successfully parsed numerics from a characters string into a new column, however for instances when there are multiple numerics it produced a character string in that specific row. Any Ideas for a summation of this particular case. I have provided an example. Keep in mind I would like to maintain the integrity of the singular numerics.

My previous parsing produced this in the row c("40", "8"), how do I make it 48?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You've to first convert the vector to number the using as.numeric() and then sum the vector using sum() function.

```
sum(as.numeric(c("40", "8"))
```

Output : 48

Comment: is there a symbol I can use to run that code on all numerics because there is multiple cases in the column not just 40 and 8

Comment: It'll work for a vector with  any number of items inside the as.numeric() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dataframe called `df` and column with `col`, you can do :

```
df$total <- sapply(df$col, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```